# How to downgrade Data binding libary to use only 25 version?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm stuck on compileSdkVersion 25 and targetSdkVersion 25 (not allowed to update), latest Data binding libary requires 26+ and return error if I compile using 25. (path-to-app\app\build\intermediates\data-binding-layout-out\debug\values-v26\values-v26.xmlError:(15, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.)  And chance to downgrade ?

Comment: There is no really good reason to stick with a lower `compileSdkVersion`, except for creating historical builds. If you are doing ongoing development, keeping up to date with `compileSdkVersion` and libraries is fairly important, for bug fixes if nothing else. Whoever is telling you that you are not allowed to update the `compileSdkVersion` is making a mistake IMHO. With respect to your problem, since we do not explicitly depend upon data binding artifacts, downgrading is likely to be tricky at best.